# jQuery - addClass if day is today

Tags: jquery, addclass

Simple question; I want to highlight some text if it is monday, some other when it's tuesday etc.

```
$('p.day:eq("' + new Date().getDay() + '")').addClass('today');
```

I feel like I'm so close.

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/keE2f/1/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should do :

```
$('p.day').eq(new Date().getDay()-1).addClass('today');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('p.day:eq(' + new Date().getDay() + ')').addClass('today');
```

You need to take out the quotes in the `:eq()` - pass the value as an integer, not a string.

Also, using `.getDay()`, Sunday is day number 0, so you'll either need to change the order of your days, or create another work-around for this.

Comment: This **is** an answer. Moving the selector to another function `.eq()` doesn't explain anything

Answer (score 2):

```
$('p.day').eq(new Date().getDay()).addClass('today');
```

[**Fixed DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/keE2f/2/)

Or using the `:eq` psudo css selector:

```
$('p.day:eq(' + new Date().getDay() + ')').addClass('today');
```

The number should be a number and not a string.

Comment: @zerkms. well... You win some and lose some. At least I'm pretty `:)`